# MATLAB: How to delay a signal with noise

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have an input signal `s(n) = [1 -1 0 -1 1 -1 1]`. 
The output signal is a delayed version of the input signal with noise:

```
x(n) = a*s(n-D) + w(n)
```

How do i delay the input signal by D?

Answer (score 0):

You can pad the signal with zeros.

```
x = a * [zeros(1,D) s]
```

Comment: Yes thankyou, that is what i was trying although keep recieving an error:"matrix dimensions must agree"